# Set column in database table after defined time period

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, triggers

I have a database table with columns - `create` and `actual`. And I need a help witth trigger or something other solutions, which checks a `create` column and if is older than 1 week, automaric set column `actual` to another value. How can I do this? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can adopt `mysql event scheduler` or `cron` which will run once everyday to accomplish that. Trigger is of no use here

Answer (score 1):

The best approach to this type of problem is *not* to change the data in the database.  Instead, just use a view to calculate the actual value correctly.

```
create view v_table as
    select t.*,
           (case when datediff(curdate(), created) >= 7 then 4
                 else old_actual
            end) as actual
    from table t;
```

You can then access the value through the view.

Scheduling an event is fine if you have to do this one time for one row.  However, if you end up with a busy database, you'll end up with a zillion scheduled events, all slowing down the processing on the server.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i created. You can watch:

```
    CREATE EVENT `archive` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2016-09-18 13:34:07' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE COMMENT 'set actual' DO update results set actual = 4 where DATEDIFF(curdate(), created) >= 7;
```